# How to create a new instance of a function without overriding other instances in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
    function wasCalled() {
        if (typeof (called) === "undefined") {
            console.log("This is the first time this instance runs")
            called = true
        }
        else {
            console.log("this is not really a new instance")
        }
    }
    a = new wasCalled()
    b = new wasCalled()
```

It checks to see if the instance of the function already ran. I'm missing something obvious. What is it?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekoo6pef/

Check the console.

This is the output:

```
    This is the first time this instance runs
    this is not really a new instance
```

My hope is to get "this is the first time this instance runs" for both calls.

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Then dont create the `called` variable? Btw that called variable is global, if you wanted it as part of the instance you should use `this.called`, or use `var called` if you want it as a local variable

Comment: I'm either not understand you or you are not understanding the question. I created it in order to see if the variables get "refreshed" for the new instance

Comment: Why are you using a "called" variable ? and an if ?
The thing is, as you're creating the variable "called" as global (because you are not using "var called" declaration), then it stores the states for the next call

Comment: Is this some kind of exercise to understand closures?

Comment: Oh!! when you don't use "var" it creates a global variable!! I didn't know this!

Comment: add the line: "use strict" to the top of the file (or to the 1st line of the function) to help catch accidental global variables.

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem is. Clearly `a != b`, so you are creating two distinct instances, even if the constructor was called twice and manipulates that global `called` variable.

Comment: @Gonzalo.- you want to write your comment in the form of a question so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, as you're creating the variable `called` as global (because you are not using `var called` declaration), then it stores the states for the next call of your function (and there, you see the difference in the second call)